# Introduction to Reidemeister--Schreier Method

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I am learning Reidemeister--Schreier method, a method determining explicitly presentations for subgroups of a given group. Can anyone recommend some introductory material, preferably those with detailed examples of computation on this topic?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398375/intuitive-understanding-of-the-reidemeister-schreier-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best book for this is [Johnson](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Topics_in_the_Theory_of_Group_Presentati.html?id=L_E6AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521231086)).  Also very good is the classic [Magnus, Karrass and Solitar](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Combinatorial_Group_Theory.html?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC&redir_esc=y) ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486438309)), which has a large number of exercises for practice.