# Reidemeister-Schreier rewriting process. How to find the appropriate transversal element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

It's not clear for me how to find the appropriate transversal element in the next example below for an example for $x,y,z$ elements.

Please would someone show this process completely?

[image]

Comment: There is a worked example of Reidemeister-Schreier in section III.8 of course notes of mine:  https://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/cgtnotes.pdf

Comment: @ahulpke Thank you

Comment: You might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/810984/10513) old answer of mine helpful. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59424/10513) worked example. (Both examples take a more topological point of view.)

Comment: @user1729: thank you for your respond. The Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm could be used for normal and not normal subgoup (abnormal). Am I right?

Comment: @Metso yes, the algorithm works for all subgroups. It's particularly nice for normal ones though, as the cosets are easier to find.

Comment: (Also, I've never heard non-normal subgroups called "abnormal" before. I would advise just calling them "subgroups". Giving them a name implies that they have a property, rather than lacking a property. For example, there is a type of subgroup called "malnormal", and people may assume abnormal=malnormal.)

Comment: @user1729: ok, agree with your terminology. If a subgroup is not normal,  is it  enough to find left or right cosets for R-S method, but not both?

Comment: @Metso Yes, just find left cosets *or* right. You choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $S_3$ is defined as $\langle a,b \mid a^2 = b^3 = 1, ba = ab^2\rangle$, where $a = (12), b = (123)$.

The elements $ba$ and $ab ^ 2$ are both equal $(23)$. Since there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $G/H = S_3$, the elements $ba$ and $ab ^ 2$ are in the same coset. Therefore, the Schreier representative $ba$ is equal to $ab ^ 2$.